# windows vbs cannot get errorlevel when using curl & findstr

Tags: curl, vbscript, pipe, findstr

I'm trying to use the vbs script to curl an url then get the script errorlevel.
but always got 6 returned.

this can get the right errorlevel

```
C:\Users\lo>curl -Iks https://www.baidu.com | findstr /i 200
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
C:\Users\lo>echo %errorlevel%
0
C:\Users\lo>curl -Iks https://www.baidu.com | findstr /i hahaha
C:\Users\lo>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

below is vbs script

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
rc1 = shell.run("curl -Iks https://www.baidu.com | find /i 200", 0, true)
WScript.echo(rc1)

rc2 = shell.run("curl -Iks https://www.baidu.com | find /i hahaha", 0, true)
WScript.echo(rc2)
```

BR//lo

Comment: CMD is the program that does rediection so it must be running.

Comment: using comspec /c can got the right errorlevel code.
rc2 = shell.run("%comspec% /c curl -Iks https://www.baidu.com | find /i hahaha", 0, true)